# How to remove any custom excel formatting while working with xlrd package in python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

While I was getting data from an excel file obtained online, I saw that the date format was showing up as numbers instead of date. ex. 1/2/2003 was showing up as 41645.0. I was wondering if  there was a way to remove any and all formatting done to the excel file and have it purely be cells of strings.

Comment: Excel stores dates as floating point numbers. [xlrd documentation](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html)